# How to I map an enum ordinal to it's value in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums, hibernate-mapping

I have 2 database tables:

1. Persists a class, that has a field who's type is an enum. In the respective column, the enum value's ordinal is stored.
2. Persists the enum values' ordinal and name.

How do I use a Hibernate Mapping to map the enum's ordinal in table 1 to the name stored in table 2?

Edit:
Basically, with a SQL SELECT, I would join the 2 tables using the ordinal, to get the name. I'm not sure how I would do that in hibernate though.

This isn't a duplicate; I'm not using Hibernate reverse engineering.

Comment: When we say mapping in the context of object relational mapping, we mean mapping objects to rows in a table and vice versa. What do you mean with "map the enum's ordinal to the name"? How is this supposed to look like in world of classes and objects?

Comment: @meriton The object would be a row in the first table.  The column that represents the enum varible stores the ordinal instead of the name.  So I want to grab the name from the second table.

Comment: Can you use `MyEnum.values()[table1.getMyEnumNumberColumn()]`?

Comment: @Bohemian Can you expound on that solution?  I'm not sure where that would go.  I don't have a reference to the table.  The hibernate mapping abstracts that away.

Comment: The name of the enum can be retrieved from the enum instance by accessing its `name()` method. The instance can be retrieved from the enum class via its `values()` method, which returns an array of all the instances. So, give the ordinal number of the enum, which you get from the column of table1, you can use it as an index to the array, then use name(). All together, given an entity instance, you get `MyEnum.alues()[entity.getMyEnumOrdinal()]`

Comment: @Bohemian That's how I implemented an Ordinal version of the custom EnumUserType I wrote.  I have no issues working with Enums in java.  My problem is with hibernate, and figuring out how to store a key and pull the value from another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a custom implementation of `org.hibernate.usertype.EnhancedUserType`, overriding `nullSafeGet`, `nullSafeSet`, `fromXMLString`, `objectToSQLString` and `toXMLString` to all use the `ordinal` instead of the `name`.

It works, but I don't like it because it defeats the purpose of an enum, to not have to deal with messing with the ordinal value.  As it stands, reordering the enum values will invalidate all data in the database.

This solution completely ignores the 2nd table, the one that stores the enum's ordinal and name.

Comment: Hibernate defeats the purpose of storage abstraction

Answer (score 1):

You can have the Java side as:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
@Column(name = "user_type")
private UserType userType;  

public enum UserType {
    CLIENT,
    ADMIN;
}
```

and the SQL side:
    CREATE TABLE user (
        id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
        user_type bigint NOT NULL
    );

```
CREATE TABLE enum_user_type (
    id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(255),
    desc text
);

ALTER TABLE user ADD CONSTRAINT user_type_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_type) REFERENCES enum_user_type(id);


INSERT INTO enum_user_type (id, name, desc) VALUES ( 0, 'CLIENT', 'This is a client');
INSERT INTO enum_user_type (id, name, desc) VALUES ( 1, 'ADMIN', 'This is an admin');
```

So in java you always set:

```
user.setUserType(UserType.ADMIN);
```

In the user table the enum is stored using the ordinal.

Since you already have an enum associate table, you can use it in SQL JOINs with native queries.

If you find that you need to use HQL to fetch the enum name or description than maybe the enum should be promoted to an Entity.

Comment: How would I do this using XML?

Comment: Haven't used XML mappings for a long time, so you have to check the docs.